# Composition of linear transformation and domain and codomain

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to do a problem regarding composition of linear transformation from my book. I want to know if my reasoning is correct.

$$T_1(x,y,z)=(2x+3y-z,x-y+z,2x+9z,3y-10z)$$

$$T_2(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(9x_1 - 3x_4,2x_2 + 4x_3 - 2x_4,2x_3 + 2x_4)$$

Q1. State domain and codomain of $T_2\circ T_1$ and $T_1 \circ T_2$.

Since for $T_1$ we are going from $\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^4$ and for $T_2$ from $\mathbb R^4\to \mathbb R^3$
,domain of $T_2 \circ T_1$ will be $\mathbb R^3$ and Codomain will also be $\mathbb R^3$

Domain of $T_1 \circ T_2$ will be $\mathbb R^4$ and codomain will also be $\mathbb R^4$.

Q2 Why are $T_2 \circ T_1$ and $T_1 \circ T_2$ well defined?

$T_2 \circ T_1$ is well defined because the range of $T_1$ is $\mathbb R^4$ and $\mathbb R^4$ lies in the domain of $T_2$.

Similarly for $T_1 \circ T_2$, the range of $T_2$ is $\mathbb R^3$ and lies in the domain of $T_1$ which is $\mathbb R^3$.

Is my reasoning correct? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You could improve the readability of your question by using MathJax to type the equations.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer to Q1 is correct!

For Q2, first note that the range (image) of $T_1$ cannot be $\mathbb{R} ^4$, since $\dim\operatorname{Ran} T_1 \leq\dim \operatorname{Dom} T_1 = 3$.
The range of $T_1$ consists only of those vectors that are of the form $v = T_1 w$ for some $w\in\mathbb{R}^3$.

To show that $T_2\circ T_1$ is well-defined, it suffices to see that the range (or just the codomain, since the range is a subset of the codomain) of $T_1$ is a subset of the domain of $T_2$. This means that $T_2$ can be applied to any output of $T_1$. But you have already seen that the $\operatorname{Dom} T_2 = \operatorname{Codom} T_1$.

The same reasoning goes through for $T_1\circ T_2$ being well-defined. Again, domain of $T_1$ and codomain of $T_2$ coïncide.